# Which pronoun shall I use in this context?

Tags: pronouns

> Humans ought to  treat others as a human being would treat others.
>   Never should **they** bully and abuse anyone. Since the ultimate goal of **them** is
>   to let everyone become capable of living an appropriate and decent
>   life, **they** must pay special attention to the worse-off people, while at
>   the same time encouraging excellence and creativity, making every
>   individual capable of fulfilling his own goal.(self-made)

Here I am speaking of a kind of universal ethic for human beings. I am using the pronouns *they/them* because I want to put myself in the position of a disinterested spectator. I am concerned that representing mankind with *they/them* might be inappropriate.

Comment: No such issue at all. "I am from Timbuctoo. In Timbuctoo, **they** speak a strange dialect." (I am part of *they* here.) Well, assuming it's not an existential *they* in this example.

Comment: I am putting this on hold because it seems to generate answers that are all over the map, and because the question is very strange in the first place. Please clarify why you think it could be inappropriate to use *they* for humans. (Though I guess even if you do, this will be a better question for our sister site for learners of the language.)

Comment: “The ultimate goal of them” is something no native speaker, nor even moderately fluent non-native speaker, would have say.  It must be “Their ultimate goal” instead.

Answer (score 1):

To use *they* to represent a singular person (gender neutral) is accepted now. It should be acceptable, then, to refer to a human or humans in this manner.

- A person should not seek to injure animals; since a human is sentient,
  they should respect sentience in other species.
- *Humanity* should not seek to injure animals; since humanity is sentient, they should respect sentience in other species.

I would change a few words in your example, however, just for clarification and grammar. But not to change *they/them*. I also placed humanity in closer proximity to *they* in the third sentence to make it clearer whom was represented by *they*. I also changed *his* to a form of they for consistency.

> Humans ought to treat others as *they* would want to be treated. *They* should never bully and abuse anyone. As the ultimate goal *of humanity* is to let everyone become capable of living an appropriate and decent life, *they* must pay special attention to those who are worse-off, while encouraging excellence and creativity, making every individual capable of fulfilling <strike>his</strike> *their* own goal.

Comment: Interestingly, I find the ‘they’ used in your example sentences to be somewhat unnatural, or at least confusing. I would assume, as is common in English, that ‘they’ refer back to the _closest_ possible antecedent. Since that is ‘animals’, and since the actual antecedent is singular (which makes the link between anaphor and antecedent less obvious), I read the sentence as inferring that animals are sentient, which of course they are. It is almost a garden-path sentence in that respect. In your second sentence, ‘it’ would be more natural to me than ‘they’.

Comment: I am seeing a number of issues with this answer. Using *they* to represent a singular person is not accepted now; it has been accepted forever. However, *they* does not represent a singular person in OP's example. It refers back to *human beings*. Plural. Likewise, in your first example, as Janus points out, *they* refers to *animals*, not the *person*. Since you actually want to refer to the person, your example is a garden-path sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I would defer to the use of “they” and reword to be consistent to that & use the word “humanity” instead to more clearly state who the “they” is in the 3rd sentence.

> Humans ought to treat others as a human being would treat others.
>   **They** should never bully and abuse anyone. Since humanity’s ultimate goal is to let everyone become capable of living an
>   appropriate and decent life, **they** must pay special attention to
>   the worse-off people, while at the same time encouraging excellence
>   and creativity, making every individual capable of fulfilling his own
>   goal.(self-made)

Comment: -1 That's not the question, though.

Comment: That would be proof-reading/ writing advice, wouldn't that be :)